# Shibboleth with Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, shibboleth

I am trying to follow up some documentation on integrating Shibboleth IDP 3 with Azure for SSO purposes, and in my application I receive an exception when I try to acquire a token (AcquireToken()):

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll
>
> Additional information: missing_federation_metadata_url: Federation
>   Metadata Url is missing for federated user. This user type is
>   unsupported.

I am trying to understand what this is telling me. The best I can tell is that it's expecting me to upload metadata in ACS (Access Control Service) but I do not see this documented anywhere. Is this what it means? If so, how can I get the right metadata to upload? In shibboleth, I can only find a boilerplate metadata.

If I'm going down the wrong path, could someone help clarify?

EDIT: Please note I'm doing this as an investigation, and I'm pretty new to setting up a federated setup. I may be doing this totally wrong. This is what I've done so far, and the issues I've identified.

1. Set up a domain in Azure, and connected it to my onprem domain using Azure Connect tool. Sync is going ok. Azure shows the domain as verified.
2. Installed Shibboleth 3, with Jetty 9.3 on my own server (not in Azure). Added the azure metadata to Shibboleth.
3. Converted my domain to SSO. I can validate that if I try to log in as a domain user into azure through the azure web login, it sends me to "https:///idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO' url.  However at this point I get a "web Login Service - Unsupported Request: The application you have accessed is not registered for use with this service". I am trying to solve this issue right now. I am not sure if it's related to the issue in question.
4. created a webapp and a native client in azure to use for testing. When I run the native app, it gives me the error mentioned above. Many guides talk about Office 365 integration, I just want to integrate with my own service.

To get to this point, I followed various guides, such as the following. In some cases it was hard to tell if the guides for Shibboleth 2 or 3.

- [Configure Shibboleth for use with single sign-on [msdn]](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205463)
- [Office 365 [shibboleth.net]](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/Office+365)

plus additional ones in various blog posts which more or less followed the same approaches.

[EDIT2] ADAL usage:

I tried a few variations, executing from a domain-joined machine:

```
var authority = "https://login.windows.net/{mytenant}";
var uc = new UserCredential(upn);
string native_client_id = "... native client uuid from azure...";
Uri native_client_redir = new Uri("... native client redirect uri from azure...");
...

// this gives above mentioned error
        ... = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, native_client_id, new UserCredential())

// these bring up the generic login form, and once I type in my UPN, the form    
// goes away and it dies with an authentication_ui_failed error.     
// I suspect this is pointing to somethign wrong with my Shibboleth    
// installation or some URL in Azure being misconfigured? I was also hoping     // it took the username as a hint.

... = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, native_client_id, native_client_redir,
            PromptBehavior.Auto, new UserIdentifier(upn, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId))

or

... = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, native_client_id, native_client_redir)
```

What I am trying to get to is:

1. Be able to authenticate my domain user.
2. Hopefully in the end allow SSO without prompting, based on my domain
   credentials.

Comment: Can you provide more info about your setup? From the error it appears you are using ADAL, but it's unclear how you set up your solution (are you federating your IdP with Azure AD? With ADFS? Are you trying t get tokens out of it directly?) or what version of ADAL you are using or what token acquisition flow you are pursuing, Please add more info and we'll do what we can to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you for reading. Done, I've added some more detail. I feel embarrassed that I can't properly articulate this whole process yet. :(

Comment: Thanks for the extra details but you omitted the info about adal usage. Some adal flows with onprem providers require wstrust endpoint sand if you are indeed using one of such flows you won't be able to use shibboleth directly. You should however be able to use flows in which we authenticate the user via pop up

Comment: Added. It's very trivial and probably wrong.

Comment: The UserCredential flow won't work given that shibboleth does not offer the programmatic auth flows this requires under the hood. The last 2 calls should work form the ADAL standpoint, but if you are getting an error that likely means that the federated tenant SSO settings are misconfigured. Hopefully somebody from the service side can chime in and help.